# How to query data and its count in multiple range at same time

Tags: sql

I have a table like below,

| id | number | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 12 | 2020-03-02 |
| 3 | 23 | 2020-09-02 |
| 4 | 11 | 2019-03-04 |
| 5 | 12 | 2019-03-23 |
| 6 | 23 | 2019-04-12 |

I want to know is that how many times each number appears per year, such as,

| number | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 |

I'm kinda stuck.. tried with left join or just a single select, but still, cannot figure out how to make it, please help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT C.NUMBER,
SUM
(
   CASE 
    WHEN C.DATE BETWEEN '20190101'AND '20191231' 
      THEN 1 ELSE NULL 
   END
) AS A_2019,
SUM
(
  CASE 
    WHEN C.DATE BETWEEN '20200101'AND '20201231' 
    THEN 1 ELSE NULL 
  END
) AS A_2020
FROM I_have_a_table_like_below AS C
GROUP BY C.NUMBER
```